# Argument Exception when calling remote appdomain method with local argument after .exe got renamed

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I have written a program in C# which loads it's own assembly in another appdomain:

```
AppDomain otherAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("otherDomain");
otherAppDomain.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName());
```

In the original AppDomain I am creating an object (Anchor anchor) and use it as argument when calling a method of an object of the other appDomain.

```
Anchor anchor = new Anchor();
RemoteObject ro = (RemoteObject)otherAppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(Application.ExecutablePath, typeof(RemoteObject).FullName);
ro.DoStuffInTheOtherAppDomain(anchor); // <- Exception happens here
```

Anchor extends MarshalByRefObject and implements an interface. Anchor and RemoteObject are in the same assembly (the executing assembly).

DoStuffInTheOtherAppDomain with it's full signature: public void DoStuffInTheOtherAppDomain (Anchor anchor).

After compiling my code **this works perfectly**. But if **I rename the .exe file** (say from a.exe to b.exe) I get the following Exception:

```
 System.ArgumentException: The object type cannot be converted to the target type
```

I marked where exactly the exception occurs in the second code block.

**Why does this happen and is there a way to avoid it even when I rename my .exe?**

Comment: You cant just rename a .NET assembly ;p Rename it via ILMerge or Mono.Cecil.

Comment: I am simply afraid users could (accidentally) rename the .exe with the consequence of it not working. Is my only alternative shipping a .dll?

Comment: You could always check if the assembly name matches the module name, and ask the user if it is OK to rename all their spreadsheets ;p